# Employee Attendance calculation script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can any one help me out how to calculate employee attendance, Here is my front end:
[enter image description here][1]
All the employees are listed out here from data base, I need to store their attendance by monthly.
User can only give "No.of days absent", whenever user enter "no.of days absent" field, the "No.of days present" field should update the no.of days present field. and I need to repeat this to all the employees listed out here.

```js
Date.prototype.daysInThisMonthOfThisYear=function() {
  return new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
}
var days_inmonth = new Date().daysInThisMonthOfThisYear();

$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#absent_days" ).keyup(function() {
   var days = $('#absent_days').val();
   $( "#present_days" ).text( days_inmonth - days ); 
  }) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="empform" method="post" action="">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="emptable">
            <colgroup>
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="head0" style="width:5%">S.No</th>
                <th class="head1" style="width:15%">First Name</th>
                <th class="head0" style="width:15%">Last Name</th>
                <th class="head1" style="width:15%">Department Name</th>
                <th class="head0" style="width:20%">Mobile Number</th>
                <th class="head1 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days present</th>
                <th class="head0 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days absent</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th class="head0">S.No</th>
                <th class="head1">First Name</th>
                <th class="head0">Last Name</th>
                <th class="head1">Department Name</th>
                <th class="head0">Mobile Number</th>
                <th class="head1">No.of days present</th>
                <th class="head0">No.of days absent</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>IT Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div id="present_days"></div></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" id="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div id="present_days"></div></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" id="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div id="present_days"></div></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" id="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div id="present_days"></div></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" id="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>                           
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <p class="stdformbutton">
          <input type="submit" class="submit radius2" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" class="reset radius2" value="Reset" />
        </p> 
        </form>
```

Comment: We're gonna have to see the HTML of that one part.

Comment: Please see the  "Front End Screen" for HTML part

Comment: That is a screenshot. We need codes.

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you just here expecting to get free code?

Comment: Now just I am displaying static html later will change into php. After calculation script

Comment: Actually tried this code <script type="text/javascript">

Date.prototype.daysInThisMonthOfThisYear=function() {
  return new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
}
var days_inmonth = new Date().daysInThisMonthOfThisYear();

$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#absent_days" ).keyup(function() {
   var days = $('#absent_days').val();
   $( "#present_days" ).text( days_inmonth - days ); 
  }) 
});
</script>

Comment: @krish, Add that to the question. We want all the code this form is using.

Comment: @Thaillie edited the questions, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

I made small change in you HTML: you cannot have `id="present_days"` and 
`id="absent_days"` multiple time in single HTML document. `id` has to be unique to each DOM element. So instead of `id` I made them to `class`.

```js
Date.prototype.daysInThisMonthOfThisYear=function() {
  return new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
}
var days_inmonth = new Date().daysInThisMonthOfThisYear();

$(document).ready(function() {
 $( ".absent_days" ).change(function() {
   var days = $(this).val();
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".present_days" ).text( days_inmonth - days );
         $(this).closest("tr").find(".hidden_present_days" ).val( days_inmonth - days );
     }) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="empform" method="post" action="">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="emptable">
            <colgroup>
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            <col class="con0" />
            <col class="con1" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="head0" style="width:5%">S.No</th>
                <th class="head1" style="width:15%">First Name</th>
                <th class="head0" style="width:15%">Last Name</th>
                <th class="head1" style="width:15%">Department Name</th>
                <th class="head0" style="width:20%">Mobile Number</th>
                <th class="head1 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days present</th>
                <th class="head0 no-sort" style="width:15%">No.of days absent</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th class="head0">S.No</th>
                <th class="head1">First Name</th>
                <th class="head0">Last Name</th>
                <th class="head1">Department Name</th>
                <th class="head0">Mobile Number</th>
                <th class="head1">No.of days present</th>
                <th class="head0">No.of days absent</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>IT Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div class="present_days"></div><input type="hidden" class="hidden_present_days"/></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div class="present_days"></div><input type="hidden" class="hidden_present_days"/></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div class="present_days"></div><input type="hidden" class="hidden_present_days"/></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Eric</td>
                <td>Soft</td>
                <td>DB Department</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td><div class="present_days"></div><input type="hidden" class="hidden_present_days"/></td>
                <td><div></div><input type="number" name="absent_days" class="absent_days" min="0" max="<?php echo date('t'); ?>" onChange="absentdays()" style="width:100%"></td>
              </tr>                           
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <p class="stdformbutton">
          <input type="submit" class="submit radius2" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" class="reset radius2" value="Reset" />
        </p> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Welcome @krish...`:)`!

Comment: How do I pass those "No.of days present" values in input field. Means I need no.of present days in text box

Comment: where are your text boxes for no.of present days?

Comment: Actually I need to store those values in to DB so I need hidden text box to store and send to next page.

Comment: Added `<input type="hidden" class="hidden_present_days"/>` just beside `present_days` `<div>` and on `change` I m setting that hidden field too. Please check the updated code. See the value of hidden field in browser's developer console or firebug.

Comment: Thanq so much @vijayP